# What is the suitable option to fill the blank in the sentence below?

Tags: sentence

Alice is exhausted, she .............

1. is running
2. has been running
3. had been running
4. was running

Can anybody please help me in understanding the answer to this question?

Comment: It's a comma-spliced (run-on) sentence, so it's strictly ungrammatical. Is this is the entire question, and correctly quoted?

Comment: I'm afraid this is exactly the question which was asked :|

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se]. Also, OP has been given explanatory answers, but is pushing for a specific answer for a test question. (1) We are not here to *do test* for OP, but can give advice & guidance. (2) Answers already given indicate that this is **opinion-based**.

Comment: You need to change teachers.

Comment: Well, as far as learning is concerned nothing is off-topic. I know clicking on the down arrow button is pretty easy :|

Comment: @SujH As far as **this board** is concerned though, TrevorD is right.  This board is for general use questions, not for test answers.  And the way you've put the question strongly suggests looking for a specific answer. Personally, I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt because you seem genuinely confused about what the 'right answer' is for this question, but I can see why TrevorD is concerned.

Comment: This was not the only question asked. There were many others as well. This kind of did not sound right. That is the reason I posted it here. And nobody explained the answer to an extent that is satisfactory, barring Shoe. So this was something new to me, yeah it was a test question, but wasn't it something new?

Comment: @SujH please read our [about] section, this site is directed essentially to scholars of English, not learners. There is another site on the SE network, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) where this question would be perfectly on topic. Questions here are expected to be asked by people for whom English is either their native language or who have a very high level of competence in the language. Questions that are easily answered by any native speaker will get downvoted because they are not within the scope of the site.

Comment: Firstly, I was not aware of the fact that, this was for so called SCHOLARS. Second, the questions asked here does not comply with that fact. Anyhow, thanks for letting me know that there is a site which helps learners :) Cheers!

Comment: @SujH don't take this personally, and there is no call for irony. All stack exchange sites have a clearly defined scope explained in their respective [about] pages. Other users will expect you to read it and familiarize yourself with the scope. Questions that are not on-topic will be downvoted, but this is not a personal reflection on you. This site is "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" and is not designed to help people trying to learn the language. That's what [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) is for.

Comment: Making a direct statement and asking not to take it personally is sounding kind of rude. Nevertheless, I'm out of here. Just a food for thought, I accept not knowing something, but scholars won't. Instead they press the down arrow and say this is not a correct question. Awesome!

Comment: @SujH: You're not being fair. I consider myself a scholar, but help learners with basic English (usually in my back room). But I wouldn't want people clamouring for such help either at three in the morning or when I was chatting with a friend. This website expressly says that it is not intended for learners of English, and has a pointer to a website not intended for those more proficient. Would it be reasonable for a child just learning the basics to demand that university lecturers take over its tuition? (Though I agree with terdon's advice here.)

Comment: I would have happily switched to the ELL site if I was asked to. But instead, I was told that the question is not right and other things. Fine, it was a mistake that i posted this here, but there's a so called POLITE way, and yea @terdon was polite to an extent, I ain't talking about him. And it's not that I'm knocking the doors to answer my question or something like that. Well, i guess I'm acting like a stubborn kid. But just give it a thought.

Comment: Now I've tuned in to the content here, I'll add: there is no conclusive evidence for the assumption that 'Alice is exhausted; she .............' is what is intended rather than the erroneous 'Alice is exhausted, she .............' . Choosing 'Alice is exhausted - she .............' instead, options 1 and 2 are both obvious choices.

Comment: @SujH the thing is, the question _is_ a very bad one. I mean the actual question about Alice, seriously, if an English teacher gave you this as a test you should change teachers.

Comment: well, alright. I don't want you to curse me for my ill-mannered behavior. I wish I could have changed her :D But thanks for everything. I know I wasted some of your precious time. Sorry for that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected answer is:

> A2. Alice is exhausted; she has been running.

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p458) notes that one use of this tense (the present perfect progressive) is for:

> actions and situations that have just stopped

Swan explains:

> We use the present perfect progressive for actions and situations
>   which have just stopped, but which have present results.

Swan lists these examples, the first of which is similar to the OP's:

> You look hot. - Yes, I've been running.
>
> Sorry I'm late. Have you been waiting long?
>
> I must go and wash. I've been gardening.

Comment: I have no clue how you managed to remember that quote of his and also the page number!! Nevertheless, I'm happy that I got it right :)

Answer (score 0):

When joining two clauses, it usually sounds better to maintain the same tense, but it isn't a necessity by any stretch.  Any one of your choices is acceptable.

The problem I suspect you are concerned about is the tense of your first clause and its relationship to the second.

> Alice is exhausted

This is a present tense verb (she is currently in a state of exhaustion), but it was caused by an event that happened in the past.  The easiest solution is simply to add a coordinating conjuction:

> Alice is exhausted because ...

In this instance, again anything works. That said, the "because" is implicit, so it really is unnecessary.

Comment: This was asked in a test. What would be the most appropriate answer?

Comment: You will have to ask your teacher that.  As Affable said, all of these answers can be correct.  Are you certain there isn't an additional instruction in answering the question that you haven't included?  Such as matching tense?

Comment: I was just about to say that the pluperfect (“she had been running”—incidentally, I’ve never heard anyone call the English pluperfect an ‘aorist’ before) would **not** be possible here. “She is exhausted, [because] she _had been_ running” does not parse. “She _was_ exhausted, [because] she had been running” works fine, of course, but using the pluperfect with a present is very odd to me.

Comment: (After Affable Geek’s edit to the answer:) Number two is _not_ a present progressive—number one is! Number two is a perfect progressive.

Comment: @Zibbibz.......well, this is all it was given. I answered she "has been running" . Because it is the one which sounded the most appropriate to me when I read it over and over again. Can't there be a one firm answer?

Comment: A firm answer would be great!